# Problem with turntable Audio Technica LP 120

Tags: turntables

I bought the Audio Technica LP 120 turntable with a amplifier: Denon AVR-S760H
I also got some passive speakers.

When I connect Bluetooth to the amplifier, it sounds good in both speakers.
But when I try to listen the turntable via "Phono" in the same amplifier, I hear muffled sound.
The turntable and the amplifier are connected via RCA cables.

Can someone help figure what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you happen to be using Line output on the turntable and Phono input on the amplifier? Use either Phono on both or (perhaps better) Line on both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about listening to music and not music practice or theory as outlined in the help center.

Comment: @ToddWilcox well, one could argue that a turntable can be used as a musical instrument. If the OP connects it to an amplifier, rather than mixer, he probably doesn't use it for scratching. However, the same issues could occur when connecting a turntable to a DJ mixer.

Comment: @user1079505 OP could certainly revise if that's the case.

Comment: I suggest reading both product manuals carefully, paying extra attention to the need for a phono preamp or not.